# What is the difference between tags parent, dependency and plugin (Maven)

Tags: maven

I am confused by the fact that POM.xml contains parent, dependency and plugin. Somethings something specified with parent must be again included in dependency, for example

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>my-app</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Why do I have to specify a dependency twice ? How can I use these three tags ?

Comment: You dont specify any dependnecy twice (spring-boot-starter-parent != spring-boot-starter-web), which one you mean? (However I have not checked, typically the starter parent prepars the POM and with the actual dependency you then select the type of project you want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `parent` is a POM which gets "inherited", it basically gets combined with your current POM by means of overwriting. (You can use "mvn help:effective-pom" to print the combined result). So all the dependencies and plugins in the parent will become yours (and all managed dependency versions, which is in case of spring-boot a majority).

The `dependendency` specifies artifacts you need on your classpath for compiling or testing or running your project (depending on its scope).

Whereas `plugin` is a artifact which gets executed at build time (like a compiler, report generator and stuff).

I would suggest to read a good tutorial or book on maven, my simple explanation is not enough to make good use of it. https://maven.apache.org/articles.html